# Why do my trees shine bright white in the background?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a location in Unity, and all of my trees shine in the background, then return to their normal color when I get close enough to the,.

[image: picture]

It is also not the skybox since when I disable that it still happens. How can I fix this? Why is this happening? Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't used this software before, but it appears that those trees may be outside of the depth of vision and the renderer is not applying texture.

Comment: Do you have LOD enabled for the trees? Any manipulations (offset, tiling) of the shared material containing the trees' textures? What shader do you use?

Comment: Am curious about any possible shaders as well.  I had a similar effect happen w/ a shader that had a hard depth from screen threshold.  Any chance you can post a .unitypackage or maybe a stripped down version?

Comment: @Kay I do have boundries set on them using [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/13324/i-can-walk-through-trees.html) method

Comment: @Jerdak Oh, I just had to set it the Shader to `Nature/Tree Soft Occlusion Bark` and it solved it. Thanks!

Comment: @OutlawLemur Read the tag for Unity before retagging your question incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you just need to change the [Shader](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Shaders.html) to `Nature/Soft Occlusion Bark Shader` to fix the problem. I found this on the [Tree](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/terrain-Trees.html) page, where it says:

> > Trees must use the Nature/Soft Occlusion Leaves and Nature/Soft Occlusion Bark shader. In order to use those shaders you also have to place the tree in a special folder that contains the name "Ambient-Occlusion". When you place a model in that folder and reimport it, Unity will calculate soft ambient occlusion specialized for trees. The "Nature/Soft Occlusion" shaders need this information. If you don't follow the naming conventions the tree will look weird with completely black parts.

Hope this helps!